# What do you do about accidental rollback?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, cancel

I thought roll back was just to see the original question but, instead it changes it. I in a sense "accidentally" pressed it. I re-rolled backed and got the question to normal but, I got and undeserved Cleanup badge how do I undo this completely? There should be a way to just have taken yourself from ever being listed on the wiki.

Comment: There wouldn't be a point to recording revision history if we just let there be an "undo" to remove all traces of the act, would there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rollback the rollback, like you did.  There's nothing wrong with that.  Mistakes happen.

Comment: Ehh ok then if thats all I can do.